# Caret position C# webform

Tags: c#, textbox, caret

I'm having trouble changing the position of the caret in my textboxes, on a C# webform. I've tried several different ways of using the SelectionStart setting but everytime it says ...WebControls doesn't have a definition for SelectionStart. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe SelectionStart is only available for [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx).  Use this set of properties for [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, but this is what I get now:                           Error 1 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectionStart' and no extension method

Comment: The TextBox for ASP.NET does not have a SelectionStart property.  You would probably use JavaScript to select text inside the TextBox.

Comment: I've made the textbox quite a bit larger in size, and now the caret starts in the middle, is there anyway to make it start at the beginning?

Comment: I'm not sure of a way to do that without the use of a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  You would use a combination of the focus() method then the select() method on the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript to do this - the web control doesn't have a SelectionStart property because the web control executes on the server, not in the browser. It doesn't make much sense to set the selection on the server side, since the actual interactive control only exists inside the browser.

If necessary, you can send a hint in a hidden input field from the server to the client-side and then use that hint from a bit of Javascript code to change the selection in the `input` field that was generated from your `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this on the server-side, you'd have to use client-sided JavaScript, just like without WebForms, to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
richTextBox1.Select(caret_position, 0);
```

Here caret_position is the index at which you want to place caret